# Best way to test output sent to a buffer

Tags: shell-command, async

I'm writing an [emacs package for Pipenv](https://github.com/pwalsh/pipenv.el) and the spike solution uses sync shell calls, which is not desirable for general usage. I'm now changing calls to be async (`make-process`) and for output to go to a dedicated buffer. This is all good and works. However, I now want to update my test suite. I'm not sure on the best (practice) way to:

1. Wait on the output of `make-process` for testing purposes. I am using `accept-process-output` but it does not return the actual output, only `t`.
2. Related, perhaps provide a custom filter for use in testing that collects the output into a value I can return and do assertions against.

What is the best way to test output that is normally sent to a buffer via an async shell command call?

Comment: If you want to use `make-process` you need a `process-filter` or/and `process-sentinel`. You should look at other packages how this is done. I would suggest to use xref. You have to set a filter/sentinel for a process and they receive the process and the output as arguments. It's really convenient to look at the output of a process this way.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the best way to do this is to use a custom filter for tests. This custom filter sets the process output in a variable. Using `accept-process-output` I can ensure the process has run, and then do test assertions against the variable.

Comment: If possible, please add an example of your solution to your answer, so that it will be helpful to other people who find your question.